# PHP: Fatal error when trying to access private superclass property through reflection

Tags: php, reflection

What I am trying to do is to extend a third-party library by subclassing one of it's classes. Unfortunately, I need access to a private field, so I am trying to use refelction to do so:

```
class LibraryClass {
    private $property;

    public function method() { ... }
}

class MyClass extends LibraryClass {

    public function method() {
        parent::method();

        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('LibraryClass');
        $property = $reflectionClass->getProperty('property');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $value = $property->getValue($this); // <--- Fatal error here.
    }
}
```

What happens is that I am getting a '500 Internal error' and nothing in PHP's error log.
I guess that the problem is due to polymorhic use of the reflection function (I pass an instance of `MyClass` as `LibraryClass`), but shouldn't this work, or at least throw a meaningful exception?

Any ideas on what could be the problem or how to achieve this differently? Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo: `$reflection` instead of `$reflectionClass`.

Comment: @jbafford Thanks, you're right. Unfortunately, I made it when preparing the question, the problematic code is typo-free.

Comment: We'll need more context, then. The code works correctly for me when the typo is fixed.

Comment: @jbafford Oh my, if that's the case, then the problem might lie in my configuration, not in how the function works. Thank you, that helps. ( I don't think there's a reasonable way of posting every detail of my configuration, plus this question turned out to be too particular for SO, I guess)